# Simplest way to create a dropdown in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am a beginner to MVC and now i would like to use Drop down in the form?
 i have tried using the Dropdownlistfor but it not working properly do we need any additional scripts for this.

Comment: Are you working with Razor?

Comment: Please, show the code that you've tried to implement. Another solution is to manually build the dropdown list with <select> and <option>

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc

Comment: [How to create a dropDown list in MVC4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26950614/how-to-create-a-dropdown-list-in-mvc4/26952781#26952781)

Answer (score 0):

does drop down has dynamic/Database value? Yes?
   As a first step, you need to have a model property which has the drop down values, something like

```
 public List<States> StatesDDL
{ get; set;} // get the list of values here.
```

Static drop down?
 use the plain HTML

```
<select id="_ddlStates">
<option></option>...
</select>
```

good luck...

Comment: am not able to retrieve the value from the dropdownlist on to the page

Comment: use a jQuery selector. For Example - var ddlVal = $('#yourDDLName').val();

Answer (score 0):

In the the action method of your controller, you have to set a viewbag which is filled with list.

```
ViewBag.StudentID = new SelectList(db.Students, "StudentID", "Name");
```

And in the View just use the DropDownList Html Helper

```
@Html.DropDownList("StudentID", String.Empty)
```