# how to pass value from dropdownlist to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a dynamic dropdrownlist and I want to pass selected value from dropdown to controller

ModelBEL.cs

```
public class ModelBEL
{
    public static string exmId { get; set; }
    public static string qus { get; set; }
    public static string ans1 { get; set; }
    public static string ans2 { get; set; }
    public static string ans3 { get; set; }
    public static string ans4 { get; set; }
    public DataSet exmAllData { get; set; }
}
```

Database layer class

```
public class dbEngine
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = null;
    SqlDataAdapter sda = null;
    DataSet ds = null;

    public DataSet getExamQus()
    {
        sda = new SqlDataAdapter("usp_getAllExam", con);
        ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        return ds;
    }
}
```

View

```
<select id="ddl1">
    <option>select</option>
    @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.exmAllData.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    { 
        <option>@Model.exmAllData.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString()</option>
    }
</select>
```

I use dropdown as

```
@Html.DropDownList("exam", "choose Tournament")
```

How can I pass selected value from dropdown to controller

Comment: What is the `name` of the `select` element?  That's the key for the value being passed to the model binder.  As long as the controller action has a matching parameter by that name or the model binder can find one on the model, that's where the value will be.

Comment: You need to invest some time in learning the basics of HTML, MVC and model binding. You have manually created a `<select>` without a name attribute so it wont post back, then you have used `@Html.DropDownList()` to create a select which has no relationship to your model and does nothing. [Refer this example for how to create a dropdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26950614/how-to-create-a-dropdown-list-in-mvc4/26952781#26952781) but I suggest you go the the [MVC site](http://www.asp.net/mvc) and work through the tutorials